# How to sort data with depth-first processing pre order from django model in python?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a data in the database, if you convert to json the data would be like this:

```js
[{
    'id': 27, 
    'has_sub_topic': 1, 
    'name': '123123', 
    'xml_name': '123123',
    'validated': 1, 
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': None, 
    'subject_module_level_id': 25, 
    'order': 1
}, {
    'id': 34, 
    'has_sub_topic': 0, 
    'name': 'nosub', 
    'xml_name': 'nosub',
    'validated': 1, 
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': None, 
    'subject_module_level_id': 25, 
    'order': 2
}, {
    'id': 31, 
    'has_sub_topic': 1, 
    'name': 'asdasda', 
    'xml_name': 'asdasda',
    'validated': 1, 
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': None, 
    'subject_module_level_id': 25, 
    'order': 3
}, {
    'id': 28, 
    'has_sub_topic': 0, 
    'name': '11111', 
    'xml_name': '11111',
    'validated': 1, 
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': 27, 
    'subject_module_level_id': 25, 
    'order': 1
}, {
    'id': 29, 
    'has_sub_topic': 0, 
    'name': '2222', 
    'xml_name': '2222',
    'validated': 1, 
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': 27, 
    'subject_module_level_id': 25, 
    'order': 2
}, {
    'id': 32, 
    'has_sub_topic': 0, 
    'name': 'qweqwe', 
    'xml_name': 'qweqwe',
    'validated': 1, 
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': 31, 
    'subject_module_level_id': 25, 
    'order': 1
}, {
    'id': 33, 
    'has_sub_topic': 0, 
    'name': 'zxczxcz', 
    'xml_name': 'zxczxcz',
    'validated': 1, 
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043', 
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': 31, 
    'subject_module_level_id': 25, 
    'order': 2
}]
```

I get the data using django model with this code:

```js
topics = Topics.objects.order_by('order', 'parent')
```

I want to sort the data with depth-first processing pre order, so it will be the first order parent, the sub_topic with ascending order, and the next parent, and so on. So the data would be like this:

```js
[
  {
    'id': 27,
    'has_sub_topic': 1,
    'name': '123123',
    'xml_name': '123123',
    'validated': 1,
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': None,
    'subject_module_level_id': 25,
    'order': 1
  },
  {
    'id': 28,
    'has_sub_topic': 0,
    'name': '11111',
    'xml_name': '11111',
    'validated': 1,
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': 27,
    'subject_module_level_id': 25,
    'order': 1
  },
  {
    'id': 29,
    'has_sub_topic': 0,
    'name': '2222',
    'xml_name': '2222',
    'validated': 1,
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': 27,
    'subject_module_level_id': 25,
    'order': 2
  },
  {
    'id': 34,
    'has_sub_topic': 0,
    'name': 'nosub',
    'xml_name': 'nosub',
    'validated': 1,
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': None,
    'subject_module_level_id': 25,
    'order': 2
  },
  {
    'id': 31,
    'has_sub_topic': 1,
    'name': 'asdasda',
    'xml_name': 'asdasda',
    'validated': 1,
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': None,
    'subject_module_level_id': 25,
    'order': 3
  },
  {
    'id': 32,
    'has_sub_topic': 0,
    'name': 'qweqwe',
    'xml_name': 'qweqwe',
    'validated': 1,
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': 31,
    'subject_module_level_id': 25,
    'order': 1
  },
  {
    'id': 33,
    'has_sub_topic': 0,
    'name': 'zxczxcz',
    'xml_name': 'zxczxcz',
    'validated': 1,
    'created_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'updated_at': '2021-12-02 02:19:44.962043',
    'last_editor_id': 2,
    'parent_id': 31,
    'subject_module_level_id': 25,
    'order': 2
  }
]
```

I have tried this code, it's works with json data, but it doesn't work when i get the data directly with django model from database.

```js
topics_ordered = []
for topic in topics_test:
            if topic.has_sub_topic or not topic.parent_id:
                topics_ordered.append(topic)
                for topic_sub in topics_test:
                    if topic_sub.parent_id == topic.id:
                        topics_ordered.append(topic_sub)
```

When i get the data directly with django model from database it only get the parent data like this:

```js
[
  {
    'id': 27,
    'has_sub_topic': True,
    'name': '123123',
    'xml_name': '123123',
    'parent_id': None,
    'order': 1
  },
  {
    'id': 34,
    'has_sub_topic': False,
    'name': 'nosub',
    'xml_name': 'nosub',
    'parent_id': None,
    'order': 2
  },
  {
    'id': 31,
    'has_sub_topic': True,
    'name': 'asdasda',
    'xml_name': 'asdasda',
    'parent_id': None,
    'order': 3
  }
]
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem without convert the data to json?

Comment: Not exactly sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish here, but `topic.parent` appears to be a FK relationship, so `if topic_sub.parent == topic.id:` will likely never evaluate to true as you are comparing the topic object to an int. You could either change `topic.id` to `topic` or `topic_sub.parent` to `topic_sub.parent.id`

Comment: You should have implemented a MPTT like database structure first, in order to easy get the items in tree order. Or use something like  [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) to simplify the tree operations.

Comment: I just want to sort the data from the parent and it subs by order first, and the next parent and it subs. 
topic.parent is a FK relationship to the Topics itself. I've tried to change topic_sub.parent to topic_sub.parent.id and I got this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Answer (score 0):

I though this code is going to fix the problem, but this approach is not well enough.

```js
topics = sorted(topics, key=lambda d: d.parent.order if d.parent else d.order)
```